# How can I extract paragraphs from html file (portion between <p> </p>) containing a specific word using R?

Tags: r

for exemple for this html code :

```
<p>hello world</p>

<p>the weather is fine today</p>

<p>it is fine in a lot of places in the world<p>
```

for the key word "world" the result would be :

```
hello world

it is fine in a lot of places in the world
```

Comment: Please be more precise about your data structure, e.g. whether you have a vector of elements or if this is a single string.

Comment: it's a html code in a html file..

Comment: What code have you tried that didn't work? Are you using `rvest` / `xml2` or `XML`? This isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, we are a code-writing service. Huh. Perhaps we can do it all with XPath then and not spin needless cycles in R:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

doc_txt <- "<p>hello world</p>
<p>the weather is fine today</p>
<p>it is fine in a lot of places in the world<p>"

doc <- read_html(doc_txt)

xml_text(xml_nodes(doc, xpath="//p[text()[contains(.,'world')]]"))

## [1] "hello world"                                
## [2] "it is fine in a lot of places in the world"
```

Similar idiom will work in the `XML` package if you can't level up to the Hadleyverse:

```
library(XML)

xdoc <- htmlParse(doc_txt)
xpathSApply(xdoc, "//p[text()[contains(.,'world')]]", xmlValue)

## [1] "hello world"                                
## [2] "it is fine in a lot of places in the world"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two alternatives:

**1) XML** Using the XML package:

```
Lines <- "<p>hello world</p>

<p>the weather is fine today</p>

<p>it is fine in a lot of places in the world<p>"

library(XML)
doc <- htmlTreeParse(Lines, asText = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
grep("hello", xpathSApply(xmlRoot(doc), "//p", xmlValue), value = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
[1] "hello world"
```

**2) regex** If `<p>` and `</p>` always appear on the same line as in the example then this would also work:

```
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
gsub(".*<p>|</p>.*", "", grep("<p>.*hello", L, value = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
[1] "hello world"
```